# Install Ubuntu from a small USB stick

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I'd like to install Ubuntu (Desktop or netbook edition, preferably latest version), onto a laptop using a small USB stick. (480 MB free space.)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a dedicated article on this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

In brief:

- Download the ISO.
- Download UnetBootin http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/
- Burn the ISO to your USB using UnetBootin. Your USB will become a
  liveUSB from which you can boot.
- Boot the system using USB and choose Install.

Comment: Sorry, that page requires a minimum of a 1GB USB stick, I need to run the installer from one with 480MB, so a minimal install which then downloads anything else.

Comment: That is not a problem. There are always Mini ISO available for this purpose. You can download for Ubuntu on this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: Those instructions require a CD, can I create a bootable USB drive in the same manner as the normal Ubuntu install? I'll look into that...

Comment: Yes, you can ...

Comment: You can create a bootable USB from any bootable ISO image. You can even make an ISO from a disc, then use that ISO too.

Comment: (years later) : no you can't, and @MadhurAhuja does not tell everything : your only option is to install SERVER edition of Ubuntu, but OP specifically asked for some DESKTOP edition. It's not possible at that time (it is almost possible with Debian which has a full network install iso of 640Mo)

Answer (score 4):

You can install a command line (CLI) Ubuntu using the Alternate Install or Mini iso (which should fit on your 512mb stick)

Then install Crunchbang using the alternate method: http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/26/crunchbang-linux-81001-alternative-installation/

You could also try the Lite version of CrunchBang, which is less than 512mb.

You could use Unetbootin to prepare the USB stick.

Comment: Naming of products in technology is just awful. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you find awful about it? If it's not commercial then it's not product-spamming.

Comment: @wez: Even I had the same question to Bravax. Was there any problem in my answer?

Comment: No, your answer was perfectly fine, I've up voted it, I can only accept one as the answer though. It's not your answer which was horrible it was the crunchbag, unetbootin, etc that i dislike.